# change UI of previous activities from an event from current activity

Tags: android

I'm currently developing a social app in which my home(Activity A) have a list of social feeds. Then user tap a feed (feedId:1) and new activity started (Activity B) and from there again user goes to other activities (B->C->D) using same feed(feedId:1) and on activity D user like that feeds then how should I show that the feed has been liked on back stacked activities(C->B->A) when user return to previous activity?

Comment: I think you need to change the question title to `How to make sure Activity is showing updated data`... anyway.. One option is to manage a global state (Database, SharedPrefs, Shared Object...) and re-render the Activity depending on that state when `onResume()` is called...

Answer (score 0):

Use `startActivityForResult` and `WeakReference`

When select a feed in A, store the feed object in a global `WeakReference` variable so it is the same object in the list, don't parcel it in the intent or you will lose the object reference.

Start your B activity with the selected index, use the global feed to show data. If something change, send back the current selected index to notify A to update the item by calling `notifyItemChanged` on the adapter (assume you are using RecyclerView)